# Convert matched pattern to lower case AWK

Tags: awk, ksh

I am tying to convert matched pattern to lower case, i am using following awk code but it is doing replace but also adding newline after replaced word

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS = "[&]";RS = ";";  };{ $2 = tolower($2) }{print $0}' test.txt
```

test file contents are:

```
This is test file &AMP; replacing &APOS; PATTERN
```

Output I am getting is :

```
    This is test file &amp; 
    replacing &apos; 
    PATTERN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As Ed Morton points out, this is *broken.***

<s>You want to make sure `OFS` and `ORS` are the same as `FS` and `RS`, respectively.</s>

When you modify `RS`, Awk will change its *reading* behavior; but unless you also change `ORS`, the writing behavior will remain at the default, i.e. printing newlines as record separators.

As Ed Morton points out, you also need to change the `FS` to just the single character `&` in order for your program to work.  But with that fixed, I get the expected output.

```
vnix$ awk 'BEGIN{ OFS = FS = "&"; ORS = RS = ";"; };{ $2 = tolower($2) }{print $0}' <<':'
> This is test file &AMP; replacing &APOS; PATTERN
> :    
This is test file &amp; replacing &apos; PATTERN
&;
```

Kudos for a clever solution which was already 95% there.

Comment: No, that will add a semi-colon to the end of the file, strip the newline from the end of the file, and replace all `&`s with `[&]`s. Not sure why the OP accepted this answer.

Comment: I don't see the semicolon at the end, although you are correct that the `FS` had better be changed to simply `"&"`. Updating answer.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: You're setting `ORS=';'` and then executing `print $0` so the output can't NOT end with a semi-colon. Your posted output is missing the `&;` part of the output that will be present right before your prompt on the next line.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for your persistence.  Right you are.  Unfortunately, I cannot delete the accepted answer. )-:

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this matches your needs better

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if("&"==substr($i,1,1)) $i=tolower($i)}1'
```

convert all words starting with ampersand to lowercase.

Or, if you want to specify first and last char for a match

```
 awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(match($i,"&.*;")) $i=tolower($i)}1'
```

f

Comment: no need for substr() and match(), you could just use `$i~/^&/` and `$i~/&.*;/` instead (that last is what your match() does but it should really be anchored `$i~/^&.*;$/`).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a simple one-liner to achieve this.  A short script perhaps:

```
{
  while (match($0, /&[A-Z]+;/)) {
    tag=substr($0,match($0,/&[A-Z]+;/)+1); tag=substr(tag,0,index(tag,";"));
    $0=substr($0,0,match($0,/&[A-Z]+;/)) tolower(tag) substr($0,match($0,/&[A-Z]+;/)+length(tag)+1);
  }
}

1
```

This steps through each line of input searching for upper case tags, and for each one it finds, substitutes the line using a set of `substr()` functions.

A test:

```
$ echo "This is test file &AMP;   replacing &APOS; PATTERN" | gawk -f ~/doit.awk
This is test file &amp;   replacing &apos; PATTERN
```

You can put a "shebang" at the top if you want to be able to run this stand-alone.  It'll work in gawk or BSD awk, so it should be happy in most operating systems.

Comment: It'll behave the same way in any awk. The only portability problem it will have is in locales where `[A-Z]` does not mean `upper case letters`, you should use `[[:upper:]]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a job for sed:

```
$ sed -r 's/&[^;]+/\L&/g' file
This is test file &amp; replacing &apos; PATTERN
```

If it has to be portable awk then it'd be:

```
$ awk '{rec=""; while(match($0,/&[^;]+/)) { rec = rec substr($0,1,RSTART-1) tolower(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)); $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)} print rec $0}' file
This is test file &amp; replacing &apos; PATTERN
```

Comment: Sadly, neither `-r` nor `\L` are portable, although this should work with a modern Linux `sed`.

Comment: OK, I added the portable awk equivalent.